# WordPress Multisite Completely FUBAR?

Tags: multisite

My instance of a WordPress Multisite is completely screwed up. I was having very slow loading times on pages and admin sites. Thought if I upgraded to WordPress 3.2.1 things might (fingers crossed) resolve themselves and it has only seemed to make things worse.

I think the problem may have been a plugin that grabbed other posts from another WordPress blog (that is on the same domain but not same WordPress instance) and inserted those posts into a site on the current multisite instance that is screwed up. From what I have read this has caused big problems for other multisite users.

Unfortunately I can't seem to recover from the original problem of slow loading pages. I cheked on mysql and the WordPress tables don't seem to be corrupt. I deactivated all plugins and still seem to have this issue. So i tried upgrading to 3.2.1 and now I can't even really get to some Admin pages for sites, other still slow loading.

What would be my best course of action? I do have a copy of the DB pre update as well as a copy of all WordPress files. The thing I thought to do was to revert back to 3.19 and export each site, start with a fresh install of 3.2.1 and then import each site.

Anyone have any better ideas which are less time consuming? Better ideas in general?

Im running Apache 2.2.20, PHP 5.2.17 and Mysql 5.X on a Windows Server. Hosted by me. The rest of the site is not slow at all and I have other WordPress sites workign

Comment: This is a *user-support* question. Try the [official wordpress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Answer (score 1):

> I think the problem may have been a plugin that grabbed other posts from another WordPress blog (that is on the same domain but not same WordPress instance) and inserted those posts into a site on the current multisite instance that is screwed up.

For the record, the *first* trouble-shooting step should always be to deactivate your plugins.  If your site was running slow before, merely updating isn't a fix.  Figure out what's breaking *first*.

I say this because now you have two problems:

1. You're still having slow page loads
2. The update to WP 3.2.1 broke something in your installation.

> What would be my best course of action? I do have a copy of the DB pre update as well as a copy of all WordPress files. The thing I thought to do was to revert back to 3.19 and export each site, start with a fresh install of 3.2.1 and then import each site.

The safest plan of action is to wipe everything and restore back to where you started with your backups.  Get back to where you were *before* the update ... then take some time to figure out what's causing the slowdown.

I recommend setting `WP_DEBUG` to true, installing the [Debug Bar plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) (so you can track query activity), and working your way through your plugins until you figure out what's causing the initial issue.

Once you've solved that problem, ***and no sooner***, you should update to WP 3.2.1.